# jQuery increment trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do some jQuery to navigate through sections with an increment class. But my jQuery code looks wrong. In the console there is this message

```
TypeError: nextSection.offset(...) is undefined
```

This is my codde :

```
for(var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    $('.project-' + i + '> .arrows > .arrow-bottom').click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('.project-' + i+1).offset().top()
        }, 750);
    });
```

Someone knows why it doesn't work?

Thank you!

Comment: The old problem of **closures** inside **loops**!

Comment: What do you mean ? ;)

Comment: Change `offset().top()` to `offset().top`

Comment: Only use one class for pick with a data-id the position you required

Comment: Did you closed the For?

Comment: You're also missing a space in the selector. Change it to ``'.project-' + i + ' > .arrows > .arrow-bottom'``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably with closure, try changing your code to this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
  (function(j) {
    $('.project-' + j + '> .arrows > .arrow-bottom').click(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.project-' + (j + 1)).offset().top()
      }, 750);
    });
  }(i));
}
```

You can refer to this post for more about closure and how it works, 
[How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: Minor stylistic note, on the 2nd to last line, passing the argument to the anonymous function happens /inside/ the parentheses used for invoked function expression, `}(i));`, but I have usually seen it placed outside, `})(i);`, because putting the unnamed function statement into parentheses forces it to evaluate as a function expression, which we then invoke with the argument `i`. The other way still works because the function expression is invocable right away, but clashes with the fact that function declarations are never invocable, so they are never followed by a list of parameters.

Comment: Turns out that `}());` is Crockford style...should've read Wikipedia first. Oh well...a matter of taste.

Comment: In this context, you should be extremely careful with your parentheses. What precedes the IIFE pattern can sometimes make a big problem for you, try the following two lines separately and try to spot why the error happens in the first one.
var fun = function (x) {
    console.log(x.toLowerCase());
}
(function(j){
    fun(j);
}("TEXT"));
/////
var fun = function (x) {
    console.log(x.toLowerCase());
};
(function(j){
    fun(j);
}("TEXT"));

Answer (score 1):

All the event listeners will have a reference to the same `i` which will be incremented each time (untill the point where `i` becomes the boundary `11`). So when the event listeners are called they will acess the value of that reference of `i` they got which will be `11` for all of them. So `scrollTop: $('.project-' + i+1).offset().top()` will be `scrollTop: $('.project-' + 12).offset().top()` for all of the items (which I assume not an element) and thus the `offset` will be `undefined`.

You can use an **IIFE** (**I**mediately **I**nvoked **F**unction **E**xpression) to create a separate closure for each iteration, thus the event listeners will have unique values like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    (function(index) { // index will be created for each iteration (new one every time)
        // instead of i use index
        $('.project-' + index + '> .arrows > .arrow-bottom').click(function() {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('.project-' + index + 1).offset().top()
            }, 750);
        });
    })(i); // pass i to the call to initialize index of the IIFE
}
```

Comment: This is a more thorough explanation, though it was not the first correct answer.

Comment: @PeterBehr It took some time to write it as I was looking for duplicates question on SO to vote to close it as this question is populare but didn't find something strong to redirect to.